# Vertically stretch content div with dynamic footer

Tags: css, html, stretch

I'm having problems implementing the following:

In my `index.html` I have two div's

- The `content` div on top of the page
- The `timeline` div on bottom of the page
  This div is created dynamically with jQuery so it doesn't have a fixed height

I want the content div to stretch all the way down to the timeline div. So the height of the content div always is (window-height - timelineDiv-height). When there is too much content for the content div, i don't want the page to show scrollbars, i want only the content-div to show scrollbars.

I know this is possible with javascript but I was wondering if there is a way with CSS? CSS would be easier when the window gets resized (with javascript i'd have to recalculate while resizing)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test
        <br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test
        <br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test
        <br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test
    </div>
    <div id="timeline"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#timeline {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could position both div fixed and use top, bottom, left and right for the exact position on the screen.

Comment: True, but that doesn't change anything. The problem isn't really the positioning of the divs. The problem is the height of the `content` div. If I just make both divs fixed and there lot's of content you can't see the content behind the `timeline`-div and down from there.

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called "footer at bottom" and has several implementations that require a certain structure. [Flexible footer height](http://jsfiddle.net/Awtba/) or [Fixed footer height](http://jsfiddle.net/AFj8h/)

1) Flexible footer height HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-holder">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed scelerisque velit orci. Sed imperdiet tortor id est p</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="footer-holder">
            <div class="footer-frame">  
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed scelerisque velit orci. Sed imperdiet tortor id est pretium</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2) Fixed footer height HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="w1">
        <p>Content text</p><p>Content text</p><p>Content text</p>
        <p>Content text</p><p>Content text</p><p>Content text</p>
        <p>Content text</p><p>Content text</p><p>Content text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

CSS are in jsfiddle links

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion! It's getting in the good direction but it's still not quite there... The scrollbar is still on the page and not in the `content` div. Because of this and the sticky footer there is content behind the footer. Also when there is not enough content in the `content` div, the div is not stretched down to the `footer` div.

Comment: I've solved it with javascript so [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rerty/1/) you can see what I want to accomplish. I'm just wondering if this is possible with CSS only because this might be better for performance...

Comment: for your example try use .content-holder(min-height:100%;) and init your function on page load event http://jsfiddle.net/HtX2m/

Comment: in your situation, you can not do without JS